# How to Configure a Vanilla APFS Volume for Time Machine

Tags: backup, time-machine, command-line, big-sur, acl

I'd like a way using the CLI to set the ACEs and the accompanying files so that Time Machine will recognize a vanilla APFS volume as a Time Machine volume. I need the CLI that generates the conditions needed for Time Machine. Specifically,

```
cd /Volumes \
ls \
TIME-MACHINE-VOLUME\
Macintosh HD

cd TIME-MACHINE-VOLUME\
ls -le \
total 16 \
drwxr-xr-x@ 6 root  wheel   192 Mar 29 19:55 2021-03-29-195615.previous \
 0: group:everyone deny add_file,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,writeattr,writeextattr,chown \
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  wheel  6908 Mar 29 19:56 backup_manifest.plist
```